# Vue & Axios: Why I am still getting a CORS error even I have set up my proxy?

Tags: vue.js, iis, axios, vue-router

I am still getting a CORS error after adding a proxy to my vue app.

On my **vue.config.js** it looks like this.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://website.com/",
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when I call my api using axios, my code looks like this

```
const response = await axios.post(`/api/Inbound/getData`,dataBody);
```

Yet I still have an issue with CORS and this what shows up on the console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website.com/api/Inbound/getData' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/Inbound/getData') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

I have also set up IIS to allow receiving data from cross-origin sources with the following code on **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowCredentials());
```

and editing my **Web.config** file to have the following lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any idea why this issue is happening would be great.

Edit 1:
Adding the **startup.cs** file

```
public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _config = configuration;
            StaticConfig = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration _config { get; }

        public static IConfiguration StaticConfig { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddDbContextPool<OutboundDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("APICon")));
            services.AddDbContextPool<InBoundDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("APICon")));
            services.AddDbContextPool<ManagementDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("APICon")));
            
            

            services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
            services.AddScoped<IOutboundData, OutboundSQLData>();
            services.AddScoped<IInboundData, InboundSQLData>();
            services.AddScoped<IManagementData, ManagementSQLData>();


            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Web Api", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web Api"));
            }

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();


            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the error it seems it is your backend who is redirecting the HTTP call to HTTPS. It is probably configured with `UseHttpsRedirection()` or `UseHsts()` (or both) - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Did you install [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) module in IIS? It is need to install CORs even if you have add custom header of Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: I'll take a look with that @MichalLevý, that looks like a good place to start.

Comment: The CORS module has been suggested a lot of times with a lot of forums, I guess I need to find a way to just unblock my request site from the API so I wouldn't have that issue anymore.

Comment: I noticed that vue target is http://... but console shows https://... So I think it may be a http authen issue which make CORS failed. This [article](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/how-to-debug-cors-errors/) says that response header headers must include Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must match exactly (i.e. * is not allowed) if the request included credentials. By the way, if the application run on locally, can CORS work well?

Comment: @BruceZhang my api calls are already direct from my test server outside of my computer. Interestingly, running my front-end on my computer connecting to the API has no issues, but when I deploy my app to my test server that is hosted elsewhere I get the CORS issue.

Comment: If you don't mind, please show whole startup file.  I need to know the content of request you post:/api/Inbound/getData. What's the response headers about CORS in development mode of browser?

Comment: Added the startup.cs file @BruceZhang